# how can I have a date field in mysql that will be update auto by a server?

Tags: mysql

I have a table "today" and it has a field "Current date" with data type:Date.
I inserted the current date value as a row to "Current date" (for example today is "2013-07-17") and I want that this value be updated tomorrow (and it's value be changed to "2013-07-18") and so on...

in another word I want a field that get to me current date from such a date server or something...

how can create this auto increment field in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the current date then just retrieve it on-the-fly with

```
select curdate()
```

Comment: I know what you want. But why would you want to add a date to a table and change it every day when you just can get the current date with a function call?

Comment: ahaaaa,now I cath your meaning, I tried it, very good, Thank You!